# How to integrate charts in Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to show graph and charts in my app.
For this I use charts in rails.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/223-charts

It works fine.I want to know is it possible I integrate it with active admin in rails?

Till now I can't done anything on its integration because I have no understanding how to start

Comment: Where you want to integrate in ActiveAdmin? index page? show page? a custom page?

Comment: want to show in show page

Comment: There are tons of different charts available, which one you want to integrate with?

Comment: bar chart which one used in railscast

Answer (score 1):

You can render a partial in show or index page, as shown [here](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/6-show-pages.md).

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  show do
    # renders app/views/admin/posts/_some_partial.html.erb
    render 'some_partial', { post: post }
  end
end
```

The partial can be plain old html/erb so you can include a `<script>` section with the necessary javascript to render your chart.